# How do i display button value in a text field in JavaScript(not JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, button, calculator

i have made a simple calculator and i am unable to print the value of my buttons on click onto the text field. How do i do that? I want to use JavaScript only, not JQuery. When i click on my buttons the values are not displaying on the text field "scr". How can i implement that?

here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Calculator</title>
<style>

</style>
<script type="javascript">
function display0()
{
a=document.all.f1.zero.value;
document.all.getElementById("scr").innerHTML=a;

b=document.all.f1.one.value;
document.all.getElementById('scr').value=b;

c=document.all.f1.two.value;
document.all.getElementById("scr").innerHTML=c;

d=document.all.f1.three.value;
document.all.getElementById("scr").innerHTML=d;

e=document.all.f1.four.value;
document.all.getElementById("scr").innerHTML=e;

f=document.all.f1.five.value;
document.all.getElementById("scr").innerHTML=f;

g=document.all.f1.six.value;
document.all.getElementById("scr").innerHTML=g;

h=document.all.f1.seven.value;
document.all.getElementById("scr").innerHTML=h;

i=document.all.f1.eight.value;
document.all.getElementById("scr").innerHTML=i;

j=document.all.f1.nine.value;
document.all.getElementById("scr").innerHTML=j;

k=document.all.f1.sum.value;
document.all.getElementById("scr").innerHTML=k;

l=document.all.f1.sub;
document.all.getElementById("scr").innerHTML=l;

m=document.all.f1.mul;
document.all.getElementById("scr").innerHTML=m;

n=document.all.f1.div;
document.all.getElementById("scr").innerHTML=n;

o=document.all.f1.clear;
document.all.getElementById("scr").innerHTML=o;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="f1" id="f1" method="post">
<div>
<input type="text" id="scr" name="scr" />
</div>
<br/>
<div>
<input type="button" value="7" onclick="display7()" id="seven"name="seven"/>
<input type="button" value="8" onclick="display8()" id="eight"name="eight"/>
<input type="button" value="9" onclick="display9()" id="nine"name="nine"/>
<input type="button" value="/" onclick="display/()" id="div"name="div"/>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="4" onclick="display4()" id="four"name="four"/>
<input type="button" value="5" onclick="display5()" id="five"name="five"/>
<input type="button" value="6" onclick="display6()" id="six"name="six"/>
<input type="button" value="X" onclick="displayX()" id="mul"name="mul"/>

<br/>

<input type="button" value="1" onclick="display()" id="one" name="one" />
<input type="button" value="2" onclick="display2()" id="two"name="two"/>
<input type="button" value="3" onclick="display3()" id="three"name="three"/>
<input type="button" value="-" onclick="display-()" id="sub"name="sub"/>

<br/>

<input type="button" value="CLR" onclick="displayC()"/>     
<input type="button" value="0" onclick="display0()" id="zero"name="zero"/>
<input type="button" value="=" onclick="display=()" id="eq"name="eq"/>
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="display+()" id="sum"name="sum"/>
</div>
<br/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your current code?

Comment: where is your code??/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="test" onClick="document.getElementById('textfield').innerHTML=this.value">
<div id="textfield"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

HTML

```
<button id="plus">Plus</button>
<input type="text" id="ih"></input>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("ih").value=document.getElementById("plus").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var showValue = function(val){
    document.getElementById('pressed').value = parseInt(val);
}
```

```html
<p><input type="text" id="pressed" value="" /></p>
<p>
  <button onclick="showValue(1)">1</button>
  <button onclick="showValue(2)">2</button>
  <button onclick="showValue(3)">3</button>
</p>
```